# Struggling with formula and returned data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that we use to track events and incidents:

Cell D is the date it is reported and Column E is the time it is reported.

We then move to Column I which is date fixed and cell J which is time fixed.

I then have column K which is total time in hours `=((I2+J2)-(D2+E2))*24` and column L which is total time in days `=INT(K2/24)&"-"&MOD(K2,24)`.

The issue I am facing is that when an incident is open it returns random numbers like `-43587-7.085552`, if possible i would rather this remained blank or didn't look such a mess, can anybody give me some pointers or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date is a date with a time of midnight.  And a time is a time with a date of 0.  Being zero dates from the base time.  So first I would make a single column with both the date and time.  The second column would then be the date time closed.  The third column would be =if(secondcolumn=0, “”, secondcolumn-firstcolumn)  If you want to displays time and date in seperate columns then duplicate the date and format it.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, remove Column D, make Column E date and time reported, I could also then remove I and make J date and time fixed then a 3rd column for the formula above?

Comment: Yes that sounds like it . I’m travelling so can’t actually get to excel at the moment